# Selected option returning tag not textual value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have this bootstrap select element

```
   <select id="createAxiomSelect" class="form-select">
      <option selected vale="true">True</option>
       <option value="false">False</option>
    </select>
```

I am trying to get `'true'` or `'false'` when selected.
Instead I am getting the tag `"<option selected="" vale="true">True</option>"`

I have tried many different ways to do this.
eg:

1. `$("#createAxiomSelect").find("option:selected").text()`
2. `$("createAxiomSelect").val()`
3. `$("#createAxiomSelect option:selected").text()`
4. `document.getElementById("createAxiomSelect").innerHTML`

These all return `"<option selected="" vale="true">True</option>"`

Can someone please find where I am going wrong, thank you

Comment: have you tried $("#createAxiomSelect option:selected").val()  ?

Comment: @Jnui this works when console logging, but not within a js function

Comment: Maybe you meant `value=true` (at the first `option`).

Comment: @user17517503 Same problem, I think this may be a async problem? When calling this as a console log it works fine but when inputting this value into a request it sends the whole tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.forms['<formName>'].elements['<selectName>'].value`.
**Important:** you should use `name` attribute, not `id`.

Comment: what is <selectName> referring to?

Comment: The `name` attribute of the `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#createAxiomSelect option:checked").value
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: not sure, how does he import Jquery?
according to https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ 
this should work $('#createAxiomSelect option:selected').val()
but :checked selector seems more easy

Comment: This is not correct. value is not a property in jQuery; use the val() method instead. Additionally, jQuery nicely "queries" the select form element for the value for you. There is no need to "find" the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery since it does state that in the question:
Item #2 is close. The correct syntax would be:

```
$("#createAxiomSelect").val();
```

See first the jQuery id selector requires '#'.
.val() will simply return the value of the selected option.

Note, you have a spelling error in your first option vale= rather than value=.
This will return instead the text of the option thus 'True' rather than 'true'.

Otherwise, I think you are on the right track. You can also do this using straight JavaScript, but since you are using jQuery, I'd suggest staying with that pattern and not mix and match.